# How to perform a GET method using Typeahead.js?

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I am using the Twitter [Typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) library, together with [TagManager](http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager/v3) in order to search for people from my LDAP directory and put the selected people in a tag list.

I have a Django function that returns a list of matching people in JSON format.

When I start typing in the input text field, I need typeahead to call the remote link as follows:
`http:\\mydomain.com\people_search?term=JohnSmith`

My Django function then extracts JohnSmith (form the link format, it can be seen that it is via GET method) adn returns the result in JSON format. The result should be used to populate the dropdown list in the input field.

I hope my problem was clear enough. If not, please let me know so that I can clarify.

How do I do the above? TagManager and TypeAhead seem to be pretty cool, but if I cannot autocomplete via a simple method, that would be uncool.

**Edit:**
My typeahead snippet:

```
jQuery("input#people-tm").typeahead({
                name: 'countries',
                limit: 15,
                remote: "{% url 'people_search' %}"
            }).on('typeahead:selected', function (e, d) {
                tagApi.tagsManager("pushTag", d.value);
                 });
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking. The typeahead [examples page](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) has examples of how to query data from a remote source - is that not what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I start autocompleting, I trace what is going on in the Chrome console. I see that it is calling `http:\\mydomain.com\people_search`. I want the text I am typing in the textbox to be `http:\\mydomain.com\people_search?term=MyText`

(I added my typeahead snippet as an edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#jquerytypeaheaddatasets), you just need to insert the `%QUERY` placeholder in your remote URL:

```
remote: "{% url 'people_search' %}?term=%QUERY"
```

Comment: Thanks! Take my bonus points. It worked. I missed that in the docs.